# iOS changing my app name

Tags: ios, ios-targets

I was playing around with my app and tried to rename the app. And now I have the name stuck for some reason. I want to name it "MantisX", butfor some reason I have it stuck as "DataRecorder". I went into Targets and selected my app and changed the name to MantisX. But for some reason it still shows up as *DataController*. If I go into schemes, it only let's me select `DataController.app`, even if I go into manage screens it has MantisX, but for some reason *DataController* is still around. I somehow wedged it, and I can't figure out how to change it. See the screenshots below..

[image: Project screenshot]

[image: schemes screenshot]

[image: manage schemes screenshot]

I've already tried deleting the DerivedData folder and all it's subfolders/files and deleting XCUserData and XCSharedData and build->clean and restarting xcode and deleting the app from my phone and for some reason that dumb little icon hasn't updated it's text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should select target want edit and go tab info and rename field like screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Right now the bundle display name is set to $(PRODUCT_NAME) and so I found the product name under Build Settings -> packaging. And I updated that. That did the trick.